# EasyModbus: disconnecting from network doesn't change the connection state

Tags: c#, exception, network-programming, modbus-tcp

In a C# application I use EasyModbus to connect to a remote server:

```
ModbusClient client = new ModbusClient()
{
    IPAddress = "192.168.1.100",
    Port = 502,
    ConnectionTimeout = 200
}

try
{
    client.Connect();
}
catch (EasyModbus.Exceptions.ConnectionException)
{
    throw;
}
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
{
    throw;
}
```

then in other parts of my application I try to read/write only if the client is still connected:

```
if (client.Connected)
{
    try
    {
        int[] readHoldingRegisters = client.ReadHoldingRegisters(1000, 10);
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

If while the application is running I disconnect my laptop from the WiFi network, the `Connected` property is still `true` even after a long time. I get a "out of range" exception when I try to read the registers, but I wonder why that property doesn't turn to `false` immediately. At least, I would expect a "timeout" exception when I try to read/write something.

Is there a better approach to know the server is not reachable anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not possible to detect a connection loss if the server has simply been disconnected without closing the connection. Then the `Connected` property is still `true`.

Maybe the `Available` method could be helpful. That method simply polls the server if it is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I recently faced the same issue and `Available()` also returned true since the server was reachable but Modbus Server was not working. You can fix it by calling `Disconnect()` method on catch statements if that is the case